# How do you access a node variable from javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to make a full stack application, so I am trying to figure out how I can send a server side variable to the front end? Specifically, I am generating location coordinates with node which I wish to then send to a javascript file so that it can load the location on google maps. How can I do this?

Edit: Sorry, I forgot to include that I know how to use the google maps API, I just need to send location coordinates from the back end to the front end.

The script I am using to load the google map (inside my index file):

```
// Initialize and add the map
  function initMap() {
    // The location of Uluru
    var uluru = {lat: -25.344, lng: 131.036};
    // The map, centered at Uluru
    var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4, center: uluru});
    // The marker, positioned at Uenter code hereluru
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
}
```

The node code:

```
router.post('/ZipCode', (req, res) => {
    var zipCode = req.body.zipCode;
    console.log("Zip Code: " + req.body.zipCode);


    geocoder.geocode(zipCode)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            var location = response['results'][0].location;

            console.log(location)
        })
        .catch(err => {
         console.error(err);
        }
    );


    return res.redirect('/');
});
```

I am trying to figure out how to display the new location onto the google maps API after a POST request is made.

Comment: The client uses AJAX to send a request to node.js. node.js sends the response with the data.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! could you please tell us what you've tried? (as in the code that you've written).

Comment: Sure, I added it

Comment: Check out the Fetch API to make your request client-side.  There is no need for XHR these days.

Comment: But how do I go from server to client? Am I supposed to generate an entirely new page? Is there no way to change certain components of the current page the user is on?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have a **html template page** where the data is going to be displayed. The server will respond with the JSON data, which will be filled in your html template by the template engine.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ideas that may help you to progress.

- With a framework like Express JS, you can create a Rest API that has access to your data and can send it across to the client.

See this link for a demo below that can be used to help prototype your idea:

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

In this example, the endpoint 'localhost:3000/' returns 'hello world'. However, your API can send any type of data you like, e.g. JSON, JSONP, XML, Text, HTML.

Note: the '/' can be changed to '/users' or '/api/v1/data' for example, so you can create multiple end points within your API.

With this app running,

From the front end (html / Css / Js) you can make a http GET request to the Express app

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/').then((data) => { console.log(data); })
```

To get around CORS issues you can use JSONP e.g.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.jsonp({ data: 'Send your data here' })
```

See also:

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.jsonp

https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Another way could be to create an event driven API, this would be useful if you want the data to be streamed and sent to multiple devices in realtime.

https://socket.io/

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt

See also, alternate frameworks:

https://nextjs.org/

https://sailsjs.com/

Hope this helps you move forward